# How to initiate OnClick event for each search results items so that it render a product page with meta data of that item in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, metadata, render, onclicklistener

How to create a onclick event for each search results items so that it render a product page with meta data of that item. I have successfully able to filter items as per keypress. Now I want to give a click event for filtered item to open a product page. How would I do that in Javascript? Please help me figure out this.

```
    **My HTML code**
    <!-- Search form -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="active-pink-4 mb-4 mt-4">
              <input class="form-control form_search" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="search">
            </div>
            <div id="match-list" name="matchid"></div>
        </div><!-- End of Search form -->
        
        <div class="container"><!-- Strat of login container-->
            <div class="row" id="viewhide"><!-- Strat of login row-->
                <div class="col-md-6 d-none d-sm-block"><!--start of col login img-->
                    <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/width-1200,height-900,imgsize-27424,resizemode-1,msid-14351710/industry/healthcare/biotech/pharmaceuticals/free-medicines-to-all-patients-in-government-hospitals-from-november.jpg">
                </div><!--End of col login img-->
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center fadeIn first"><!--Start col login-->
                    <h2>Sign In</h2>
                        <!-- Login Form -->
                        <form>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Username">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                                
                            <div id="formFooter">
                                <a class="underlineHover mb-2" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary d-flex justify-content-center d-md-table mx-auto mb-2 btn-round" value="Login">
                            <h5>You don't have an account ?</h5>
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary d-flex justify-content-center d-md-table mx-auto mb-5 btn-round" value="Register">
                        </form>
                </div><!-- End of col login-->
            </div><!-- End of login row-->
        </div><!-- End of login container-->
        
    **My Js code:**
    
              const search = document.getElementById('search');
              const matchList = document.getElementById('match-list');
    
              // Search states.json and filter it
              const  searchStates = async searchText =>{
              const res = await fetch('lib/json/data.json').then(response =>{
              //console.log(response);
              if (!response.ok) {
                  throw Error("Error");
                }
                return response.json();
               }).then(data =>{
               //console.log(data.item);
               let states = data.item;
               //console.log(states, "states");
    
    
            // Get matches to current text input
            let matches = states.filter(state =>{
                const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, `gi`);
                return state.itemName.match(regex) || state.itemMfrCode.match(regex);
            });
    
            let divhide = document.getElementById('viewhide');
            if(searchText.length !== 0){
                divhide.style.display = "none";
            }else{
                divhide.style.display = "flex";
            }
    
            //Hide all results when input is empty
            if (searchText.length === 0) {
                matches = [];
                matchList.innerHTML = '';
            }
    
            //Hide if no results are found
            if (searchText !== states) {
                match = [];
                matchList.innerHTML = '';
            }
    
            outputHtml(matches);
    
        }).catch(error =>{
            console.log(error);
        });  
    
         };
    
         //Show results in HTML
         const outputHtml = matches => {
         if (matches.length > 0) {
            const html = matches.map(match => `
                <div class="card card-body mb-1" id="medprod" name="selectid" 
                       onclick="getproduct()">
                    <h4 style="cursor: pointer;">${match.itemName}</h4>
                </div>
                `).join('');
              matchList.innerHTML = html;
          }
        }
     search.addEventListener('input', () => searchStates(search.value));


    //On clcik search result items function
    function getproduct(){
     }

**My Json structure** 
       
       {
           "clientId": "1234",
           "systemId": "2010",
           "orderReferenceNo": "43442",
           "responseCode": "0000",
           "responseDescription": "Items successfully retrieved!",
           "item": [
                     {
                       "itemMfrCode": "0001001",
                       "qnty": "00000000",
                       "itemName": "clinic shampoo",
                       "unitPk": "30ml",
                       "itemCategory": " ",
                       "itemType": "NT",
                       "schemeRange": "000",
                       "schemeOffeQty": "000",
                       "rateDiffFlag": "N",
                       "schemeHalfValueFlag": " ",
                       "schemeHalfValuePerc": null,
                       "ratePerUnit": 20.00
                       },
                      {},
                }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ "How would I do that in Javascript?" It looks as though you're trying to get someone to write code for you which is not what this website is for.  Please add any `javascript` code that you've tried, including the 'filter items' even if the code did not work as expected

Comment: I have posted JavaScript code in the above post. If you scroll down, you can find "My Js code". That is the code which I'm trying.

Comment: I know that this site is not for source code. Since I'm new to Javascrpit, I don't know which method or what to do after filtering method is applied to a search filter as shown in the above post. I just need the keywords(unaware of technical word) for onclick events so that I can try writing the code. As far as my research I think I need to save JSON data in a database then I need write query to retrieve onclcik element in Javascript. Am I correct? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have posted the answer long before. No problem, hope it helps someone in future.

```js
const search = document.getElementById('search');
const matchList = document.getElementById('match-list');
const productLayout = document.getElementById('product_layout');

//Search filter
const searchStates = async searchText => {
  const res = await
  fetch('https://data.json').then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error("Error");
    }
    return response.json();
  }).then(data => {
    console.log(data.item);
    let states = data.item;
    console.log(states, "states");
    matchList.style.display = 'block';

    // Get matches to current text input
    let matches = states.filter(state => {
      const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, `gi`);
      return state.itemName.match(regex) ||
        state.itemMfrCode.match(regex);
    });

    if (searchText.length !== 0) {

      productLayout.style.display = 'none';
    } else {

      productLayout.style.display = 'block';
    }
    outputHtml(matches);

  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

};

//Show results in HTML
const outputHtml = matches => {
  if (matches.length > 0) {
    //Meta data of clicked item
    //Keep adding 
    //${match.itemId},${match.itemRate},${match.itemColor} to the list.
    const html = matches.map(match => `

                  <li id="${match.itemMfrCode}">${match.itemName}</li>
                    `).join('');
    matchList.innerHTML = html;
  }
}

search.addEventListener('input', () => searchStates(search.value));

/*OnClick filtered items*/
matchList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  while (target && target.parentNode !== matchList) {
    target = target.parentNode;
    if (!target) {
      return;
    }
  }
  if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    //Get selected product name
    let liInnerText = e.target.innerText;
    //Store prod name in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('liText', liInnerText);

    //Insert selected item in input text field
    search.value = liInnerText;

    //Hide search dropdown after click event
    matchList.style.display = 'none';

    /*View product layout*/
    productLayout.style.display = 'block';
    //Get product name from localStorage
    var selectedName = localStorage.getItem('liText');
    //Dispaly product name in HTML page
    document.getElementById('prod_name').innerHTML =
      selectedName;
  }
});
```

```css
#match-list {
  display: none;
}

#product_layout {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Search form -->
<div class="container" id="search_layout">
  <div class="active-pink-4 mb-2 mt-4">
    <input class="form-control form_search" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="search" value="" autocomplete="off" onfocus="this.value=''">
  </div>
  <ul id="match-list" name="matchid"></ul>
</div>
<!-- End of Search form -->

<!--Product details-->
<div class="container-fluid" id="product_layout">
  <div>
    <p id="prod_name"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).